# How to use data from jquery appended dependent inputs in a form

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Not sure that the title I choose is very explicit. If not, sorry.

My question is if we have a form with dependent inputs like so:

```
<form>
<input type='text' name='item-1'/>
<input type='text' name='sub-item-1'/>
<input type='text' name='sub-item-2'/>
</form>
```

In this case, the sub items are directly associated with the item above.

Now, we add 2 buttons to this form.

First one will add (jQuery append) an input sub item, in this case it will be:

```
 <input type='text' name='sub-item-3'/>
```

Second button will add (also jQuery append) a all new item with its own sub items.

So we could end up with something like this:

```
<form>
<input type='text' name='item-1'/>
<input type='text' name='sub-item-1'/>
<input type='text' name='sub-item-2'/>
<input type='text' name='sub-item-3'/>

<input type='text' name='item-2'/>
<input type='text' name='sub-item-1'/>
<input type='text' name='sub-item-2'/>
</form>
```

If I use a submit button the "dependecy" of the data wouldn't pass. So I end up with something like this:

```
array(
item-1 => random value A,
sub-item-1 => random value B,
sub-item-2 => random value C,
etc)
```

So my question is how can I end up with an array which translate the dependecy of the data. Like so for example:

```
array(
Value item 1 => array(
sub-item-1 => random value B,
sub-item-2 => random value C)
Value item 2 => array(
sub-item-1 => random value B))
etc
```

Appreciate anu feedback on an other structure for the form, or a method to structure the data after. Important thing is ending up with an array that shows the dependency of the inputs.

Well hope it's clear enough, try my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the name attribute of your form inputs need to be all unique. So instead of "sub-item-1" for each "parent" you could do "sub-item-1-1", and for the next one, "sub-item-2-1".

Here's some code which would take such an array and reorganize it in a 2-d array (just swap your inputValues with your $_POST)

```
$inputValues = array(
    'item-1'=>'parent 1',
    'sub-item-1-1'=>'sub value 1-1',
    'sub-item-1-2'=>'sub value 1-2',
    'item-2'=>'parent 2',
    'sub-item-2-1'=>'sub value 2-1'
);

$outputArray = array();
//create array of parents
foreach($inputValues AS $key=>$value){
    if(is_numeric($key[5])){
        array_push($outputArray,array('parent'=>$value));
    }
}

//add children
foreach($inputValues AS $key=>$value){
    if(is_numeric($key[9])){
        $parentIndex = $key[9]-1;
        $outputArray[$parentIndex][$key] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($outputArray);
```

Edit: Just realized this wouldn't work if your item count goes into the double-digits - if so, use `substring` to extract the item/parent number from the key name instead of "`$key[5]`" or "`$key[9]`"